# ReadUncommitted not working across transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have two tables: 
TableA with columns `id(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` and `name(NVARCHAR)`( uses `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to auto-generate values for 'id' column)

TableB with columns `id( IDENTITY)`, `parentId(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)`.
`parentId` in TableB has a foreign key constraint on TableA `id`.

I'm trying the execute the following queries:

In session 1:

`BEGIN TRAN test1
 INSERT INTO dbo.TableA( name ) 
 OUTPUT INSERTED.id
 VALUES ('foo')`

Note that I do not want to commit the transaction here yet.

In session 2: 

  `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
  BEGIN TRANSACTION test2
  INSERT INTO dbo.TableB(parentId)
  VALUES('<use_id_from_session1_here>')`

The second insert fails to execute and hangs up in SQL Server Management Studio and in my application code as well.
Shouldn't setting an isolation level of 'ReadUncommitted' allow the insert in the second transaction to read what was uncommitted in the first?

Am I missing something here or the way I'm using/setting the transaction isolation level incorrect?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is when you're doing the second insert, SQL Server is trying to check the Foreign Key to make sure you're not inserting something you can't. But since the lock on TableA is still being held by your first transaction, your second transaction is waiting. Read uncommitted doesn't matter there. Constraints have to be checked before an insert can take place, so it will wait for the first transaction to finish. You'd still be violating the Foreign key constraint if the lock weren't in place because the first transaction hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: that makes perfect sense! is there anyway I can work around this with possibly keeping the foreign key constraint still in place?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And why? That will help me understand what you might be able to do.

Comment: No way around this because you could violate referential integrity if there was a way. Your design appears flawed @user3638992. Cross transaction access to the same data is really dangerous and brittle.

Comment: I corrected what I was doing in my application logic. I changed the design to use a single transaction rather than accessing the same data across transactions.

Answer (score 0):

you might commit every single insert in session 1, or every some batch of a size that don't limit too about wait time of session 2